# Android binary disassembling and debugging protection

Tags: android, debugging, encryption, disassembly, dex

let's assume I would like to protect the Android binary against disassembling or byte code debugging - are there any solutions for that available on market for both java and native C/C++ code?

Thanks a lot 
STeN

Comment: what do you mean by something on the android market for C++ ?

Comment: I mean that with NDK you can write C/C++ code and pack it into NDK together with Java code. I am asking if there are any anti-disassembling or anti-debugging solution for both - Dalvik java binaries and linux executables (for the portion of the project developed with use of NDK).

Answer (score 1):

Compiling a binary should be enough to obfuscate it and java/dalvik byte code can be obfuscated by proguard, it's [built in eclipse ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Hi, is there anything more we can do, e.g. asymmetric encryption of parts of the binary, so the Java byte code will be decoded on flight before passed for execution to the JVM? I can imagine that this is theoretically possible. But I guess nothing like this or nothing more sophisticated is available on smartphones... I was doing similar things in MS-DOS times and at that time there were many disassembling/anti-debugging techniques developed on PCs (might be this is still valid)... Is it something not used in business at all or not only on Android?

Comment: Did you ever notice that there has never been a single app on any platform written in any language which was not unprotected and spread by pirates, often before it was officially released?   Java's a funny one; it's as if the system it runs under was designed to be hacked. C++ lends itself much more to protection but I fear you'll find the average C++ hacker is a little more clued up than the average C++/Android developer and they'll have already considered your solutions and have their own solutions for them...

Comment: Hi, I am sure that everything you wrote is true and yes it will be hacked, but still I am interested if there are some solutions or not.

Comment: I used to encryp class files in java for desktop apps and decrypt them at runtime in the class loader. But I don't think this is necessary with android. It was just meant to be harder for my students to decompile the code but a real hacker would have circumvent that additional protection easily I guess. So I don't think it's worth anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It is fundamentally impossible to protect your binary by 100%. But, you can increase the complexity for reverse engineer to decompile your source code.

If you are developing your android app using JAVA/Kotlin, then reverse engineer can easily decompile your source code even if you are using Proguard/dexguard to obfuscate your code.

So, Better option is to use NDK to develop your business logic and access that in java/kotlin code. It will be more difficult for the reverse engineer to decompile your so file.